Unable to Save DataFrame as Delta Table
I'm trying to create an environment of PySpark, Delta Lake and Jupyter Notebook.
Everything seems to be using the same Spark, Scala and JDK version. (3.5, 2.12, 17.0)
I'm unable to save a DF as a Delta Table. Below code works fine with CSV but not with Delta.
Error is: : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.Seq org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.toAttributes()
So far I don't see anything that would conflict and would cause this to not work.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, "Alice", 34),
    (2, "Bob", 45),
    (3, "Catherine", 29)
]
columns = ["id", "name", "age"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/cluster/test")

Dockerfile.spark
FROM bitnami/spark:3.5.0

USER root

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

# Specify the Scala version
ENV SCALA_VERSION=2.12

# Copy spark-defaults.conf to the correct location
COPY spark-defaults.conf /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

# Download and install Delta Lake, Azure Data Lake Storage, and AWS JARs
RUN curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.4.0/delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar \
    && curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-storage/3.2.0/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar \
    && mv delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar /opt/bitnami/spark/jars \
    && mv delta-storage-3.2.0.jar /opt/bitnami/spark/jar

Dockerfile.jupyter
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:x86_64-spark-3.5.0

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

# Specify the Scala version
ENV SCALA_VERSION=2.12

# Download and install necessary JAR files
RUN curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.4.0/delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-storage/3.2.0/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar && \
    mv delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar /usr/local/spark/jars && \
    mv delta-storage-3.2.0.jar /usr/local/spark/jars
    
# Copy requirements.txt and install packages
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

USER jovyan

# Set Spark Master URL
ENV SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077

# Start JupyterLab in /mnt/cluster
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--notebook-dir=/mnt/cluster"]

spark-defaults-jupyter.conf
spark.jars                                          /usr/local/spark/jars/delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar,/usr/local/spark/jars/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar
spark.sql.extensions                                io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog                     org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

spark-defaults-spark.conf
spark.jars                                          jars/delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar,jars/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar
spark.sql.extensions                                io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog                     org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

requirements.txt
pyspark
jupyterlab
delta-spark

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  spark-master:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.spark
    container_name: spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - C:/cluster:/mnt/cluster
      - ./spark-defaults-spark.conf:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    volumes:
      - C:/cluster:/mnt/cluster
    networks:
      - spark-network
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2

  jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.jupyter
    container_name: jupyter-lab
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - C:/cluster:/mnt/cluster
      - ./spark-defaults-jupyter.conf:/usr/local/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
      - spark-worker
    networks:
      - spark-network

networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge


Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but the useless repetition of the tag information, which should not be in the title at all. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

@KenWhite give me a recommendation and I'll change it. Otherwise please focus on the question itself.

It seems like using delta-core isn't sufficient and I needed to use delta-spark instead.
By replacing: delta-core_2.12-2.4.0.jar with delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar resolved the issue.
